# very high number of queries in a second.

Tags: php, python, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I need to design a mobile application which requires a lot of database queries. A lot of means, a peak value can be 1 million in a sec. I dont know which database to use and which backed to use. In client side, i will be using phonegap for android and ios and i will be needing a webinterface for pc also.

My doubts are, i am planning to host the system online and use google cloud message to push data to users.

Can online hostings handle this much traffic? 
I am planning to use php as backed. Or python? 
the software need not be having a lot of calculation but a lot of queries.

And, which database system to use? Mysql or, google cloud  sql?

Also tell me about using hadoop or other technologies like load balancers.

I may be totally wrong about the question itself.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your experience?

Comment: GCM is the completely wrong approach for streaming/delivering huge amounts of data. It is intended to send occasional notifications to the device/app, not requiring each app to periodically poll a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google AppEngine](https://appengine.google.com/) could be the answer, it could be programmed in python or php (or java) and easily support scaling up to millions of requests per second and scaling down to just a few to save the resources (and your money).

they use their own NoSQL db, however there's a possibility to use SQL-based backend (not recommended).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, if you want to store unstructured data and retrieve it really fast, you should be looking at NoSql segment for storage and try to do a POC using a few of the available solutions in market. I would like to suggest giving a try to Aerospike NoSql DB which has a track record of easily doing 1 Million TPS on a single machine.